# How to save order of creation of fragments on Rotating device?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have made 2 fragments A and B.
B comes over A.
After i rotate device ,activity is recreated and fragments are recreated but in reverse order i.e. B then A.

Any Idea what could be happening? How to save their order of creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link must help you to solve your problem with rotate device and restart activity:

- [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

This is some link about fragment lifecycle and restart activity:

- [Android Fragment lifecycle over orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474104/android-fragment-lifecycle-over-orientation-changes)
- [Android Fragment Lifecycle of Single Instance Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611504/android-fragment-lifecycle-of-single-instance-activity)

Comment: any article related to fragment lifecycle and restart activity?

Comment: I am adding some link about fragment lifecycle and restart activity to my answer